# Converted date from oracle.jbo.domain.date to java.sql.date is exceeded by one day ahead

Tags: java, datetime, oracle-adf

I'm currently working on Oracle Business Components, I need to grab some `oracle.jbo.domain.Date` and convert it to `java.sql.Date`. I eventually knew how to do the conversion using `dateValue()`, but what happens is that the converted `date` was exceeding the original by one day.

Say: `oracle.jbo.domain.Date = 1/1/2011` ,

after `dateValue()`

```
java.sql.Date = 1/2/2011
```

Why is that happening ?

Comment: check `Locale` of both `Date` objects..

Comment: Something wrong with TZ, I guess